# Page width larger than any elements on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey everyone, working on a site at the moment.

http://www.creativefireplaces.co.uk/fireplaces/marble-fire-surrounds/sheridan-marble-fire-surround.html

If you go to that page you will see that there is a horizontal scroll bar. I have tried to find the div responsible. (i'm aware the search bar pokes out) But looking in the code I cant work out what is making the pages so large.

Answer (score 2):

`<div class="product-custom-right-col" style="">`

`.product-custom-right-col {`
`float: right;`
`width: 420px;`
`}`

The absolute width of 420 px and float right is causing the issue.

Comment: i disagree i think my answer is the reason for the overflow

Comment: but something must be causing the overflow right ? i don wanna delete another answer that just got attacked with negative votes

Answer (score 1):

add `overflow-x: hidden;` to div class middle-container :)

Comment: you will just hide scrollbars, but the problem will remain

Comment: great find , supreme ! still the inherent prob will be ther as pointed out !

Comment: Yeah but ignorance can be bliss (don't lynch me for that)

Comment: ignorance may lead to bigger problems

Comment: Yes Kasp3r i am aware of that, it was a throwaway comment not an actual suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Check your background image (the vertical stripes).  It is too wide.  Look at http://www.creativefireplaces.co.uk/skin/frontend/creative/default/images/main_bg.gif it overflows the browser horizontally.